# O que significa -rf após rm?

Tags: linux, apache, shell

Tenho um comando em `SSH` na platafoma **Magento** (instalado em um servidor **Apache**) para excluir o conteúdo da pasta cache `rm -rf path/to/folder/*` mas na verdade não sei bem ao certo o que `-rf` significa.

Comment: Só para esclarecer o conceito: o comando `rm` é do shell remoto, assim como o `ssh` é um comando do seu shell local.

Comment: `ssh` no caso seria só o protocolo, não?

Comment: @Machado o executável ssh do linux é o cliente do protocolo SSH, assim como sshd é o executável do servidor de SSH. E o comando rm não é um "comando do SSH". Localmente você executa o rm da mesma forma. Sem precisar de SSH. E o Magento não guarda relação com nenhuma destas coisas.

Comment: O Magento é só a plataforma onde o script está localizado. Em poucas palavras estou usando eventos registrados na Cron do CPanel para ler um arquivo com um conjunto destes comandos para _limpar_ a pasta **cache** do Magento. Se puder então me corrigir quanto ao meu entendimento, agradeço.

Comment: não esquecer o velho manual: `man rm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com um pouco mais de pesquisa encontrei o seguinte:

`rm` **remove / delete**:

- `-r` **recursivo** (recursively): recursivamente deleta todos os diretórios/arquivos que correspondam.
- `-f` **forçar** (force): força a exclusão sem considerar confirmação.

**src:** http://dustyreagan.com/how-to-delete-an-entire-directory-via-ssh/

Comment: Oi Machado. Eu restaurei sua resposta porque ela acrescenta conteúdo, e a edição que você fez na outra foi radical demais, e por isso acabou rejeitada pela comunidade. Achei melhor não perder as informações adicionais que você colocou. Não tem problema ter mais de uma resposta na pergunta; na verdade, isso é desejável.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, usuários assim são os que fazem novatos como eu quererem se aprofundar na comunidade.

Answer (score 3):

`-r` modo recursivo, ou seja, remove a pasta e subpastas e
`-f` remove de modo forçado, sem perguntar ao usuário

Esse comando deve ser usado com cuidado, pode danificar todo o sistema.